# swift 4 xcode app not reading in json file

Tags: ios, json, swift4, xcode9, decoding

So I have a paging app with 3 pages and each page has a details view. All three pages (views) access separate json data files. Everything worked fine until I set up the third page view and its detail view. Now the app can't seem to access the json file for the second view. It gets the path to the file and generates a local URL for the file, but either doesn't find the file or doesn't get the data out of it. Below is the code:

```
func downloadJSON(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Speedways", ofType: "json")
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil, response != nil else {
            return
        }
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            allspeedways = try decoder.decode([Speedways].self, from: data)
            var s = 0
            for speedway in allspeedways {
                self.TableData.append(speedway[s].speedway.capitalized)
                s += 1
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }.resume()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        completed()
    }
}
```

This is the data model:

```
typealias Speedways = [Speedway]

struct Speedway: Codable {
    let speedway, location, sizeOfTrack: String
    let trackEvents, trackevents: [Trackevent]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case speedway = "Speedway"
        case location = "Location"
        case sizeOfTrack = "SizeOfTrack"
        case trackEvents = "TrackEvents"
        case trackevents
    }
}

struct Trackevent: Codable {
    let trackevent, date, pole, winner: String
    let playoff: String
}
```

And this is the json data (why this displays weird I don't know):

```
[{"Speedway":"Daytona International Speedway",
"Location":"Daytona, Fla",
"SizeOfTrack":"2.5 miles",
"TrackEvents" :[{
        "trackevent" : "Advance Auto Parts CLASH AT DAYTONA",
        "date" : "Sun, Feb 11",
        "pole" : "Austin Dillon",
        "winner" : "Brad Keselowski",
        "playoff" : "No"
        },
        .
        .
        .
        {
          .
          .
          .
        }]
 },
 {
 "Speedway":"Atlanta Motor Speedway",
 "Location":"Hampton, Ga",
 "SizeOfTrack":"1.54 miles",
 "trackevents" :[{
        "trackevent" : "Folds of Honor QuikTrip 500",
        "date" : "Sun, Feb 25",
        "pole" : "Kyle Busch",
        "winner" : "Kevin Harvick",
        "playoff" : "No"
        }]
 },
```

The error shows up here during execution with the message: "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

```
    speedwaysTableView.delegate = self
    speedwaysTableView.dataSource = self
```

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: `allspeedways = try decoder.decode([Speedways].self, from: data)` this line declares an array of `Speedways`, but `Speedways` is already defined as an array (`typealias Speedways = [Speedway]`). Did you try using `Speedways.self`? Also note that `speedway`, `location` and `sizeOfTrack` are defined as **non-Optional**, so passing `nil` on them is invalid. It has to be at least an empty `String` (`""`).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why for heaven's sake are you loading data in the bundle with `URLSession`? A local file can be read without an internet connection

Delete the `typealias` and get the data with

```
func downloadJSON() { // the name of the function is pretty misleading
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Speedways", withExtension: "json")!
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
    allspeedways = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Speedway].self, from: data)
    TableData = allspeedways.map{ $0.speedway.capitalized }
    // here reload the table view
}
```

If the code crashes you made a design mistake.

And if `speedwaysTableView.delegate = self` crashes the outlet is not connected in Interface Builder

Comment: Vadian, thank you for your help. I did implement a couple of the lines of code you provided but not all of the code, some of the lines presented more errors. But I think I'm close. I think the issue has to do more with the structure of the speedways json data and the code structure to read it in. What I'm getting now is an unexpected fatal error on the try statement for decoding the file. The underlying condition is a nil response. If I comment out the code for speedways, I see the drivers and the races data on their pages along with their details views.

Comment: Then for debugging purpose wrap the decode line in a `do catch` block and handle / fix the error. I did a quick test with the JSON in the question and it worked. If the structs matches the JSON the code must not crash. And if the JSON file is in the bundle anyway consolidate the spelling of the keys (e.g `trackEvents` / `trackevents`).